# Eclipse Google App Engine - cannot run any JSP - gives 500 Error

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp

I have spent days now just trying to get Eclipse to run a basic demo Google App Engine app.  I just have a static JSP file with an empty project.  When I try to access the JSP (after the development server is started, I get the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500 
Problem accessing /guestbook.jsp. Reason: 
    Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: 7 in the generated java file 
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 8 in the generated java file 
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent cannot be resolved to a 
type 
An error occurred at line: 10 in the generated java file 
JspFactory cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 10 in the generated java file 
JspFactory cannot be resolved 
An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file 
javax.el.ExpressionFactory cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 15 in the generated java file 
org.apache.AnnotationProcessor cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 22 in the generated java file 
_el_expressionfactory cannot be resolved 
An error occurred at line: 22 in the generated java file 
_jspxFactory cannot be resolved 
An error occurred at line: 22 in the generated java file 
The method getServletConfig() is undefined for the type guestbook_jsp 
An error occurred at line: 23 in the generated java file 
_jsp_annotationprocessor cannot be resolved 
An error occurred at line: 23 in the generated java file 
org.apache.AnnotationProcessor cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 23 in the generated java file 
The method getServletConfig() is undefined for the type guestbook_jsp 
An error occurred at line: 23 in the generated java file 
org.apache.AnnotationProcessor cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 29 in the generated java file 
HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 29 in the generated java file 
HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 30 in the generated java file 
ServletException cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 32 in the generated java file 
PageContext cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 33 in the generated java file 
HttpSession cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 34 in the generated java file 
ServletContext cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 35 in the generated java file 
ServletConfig cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 36 in the generated java file 
JspWriter cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 38 in the generated java file 
JspWriter cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 39 in the generated java file 
PageContext cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 44 in the generated java file 
_jspxFactory cannot be resolved 
An error occurred at line: 59 in the generated java file 
SkipPageException cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 66 in the generated java file 
_jspxFactory cannot be resolved 
Stacktrace: 
Caused by: 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: 7 in the generated java file 
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 8 in the generated java file 
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent cannot be resolved to a 
type 
An error occurred at line: 10 in the generated java file 
JspFactory cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 10 in the generated java file 
JspFactory cannot be resolved 
An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file 
javax.el.ExpressionFactory cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 15 in the generated java file 
org.apache.AnnotationProcessor cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 22 in the generated java file 
_el_expressionfactory cannot be resolved 
An error occurred at line: 22 in the generated java file 
_jspxFactory cannot be resolved 
An error occurred at line: 22 in the generated java file 
The method getServletConfig() is undefined for the type guestbook_jsp 
An error occurred at line: 23 in the generated java file 
_jsp_annotationprocessor cannot be resolved 
An error occurred at line: 23 in the generated java file 
org.apache.AnnotationProcessor cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 23 in the generated java file 
The method getServletConfig() is undefined for the type guestbook_jsp 
An error occurred at line: 23 in the generated java file 
org.apache.AnnotationProcessor cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 29 in the generated java file 
HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 29 in the generated java file 
HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 30 in the generated java file 
ServletException cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 32 in the generated java file 
PageContext cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 33 in the generated java file 
HttpSession cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 34 in the generated java file 
ServletContext cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 35 in the generated java file 
ServletConfig cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 36 in the generated java file 
JspWriter cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 38 in the generated java file 
JspWriter cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 39 in the generated java file 
PageContext cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 44 in the generated java file 
_jspxFactory cannot be resolved 
An error occurred at line: 59 in the generated java file 
SkipPageException cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 66 in the generated java file 
_jspxFactory cannot be resolved 
Stacktrace: 
        at 
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandl er.java: 
92) 
        at 
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java: 
330) 
        at 
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java: 
439) 
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349) 
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327) 
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314) 
        at 
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java: 
592) 
        at 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java: 
317) 
        at 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java: 
313) 
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access 
$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet 
$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
        at 
com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(Privile gedJspServlet.java: 
57) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java: 
511) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166) 
        at 
com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(He aderVerificationFilter.java: 
35) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) 
        at 
com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFi lter.java: 
58) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) 
        at 
com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(Trans actionCleanupFilter.java: 
43) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) 
        at 
com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFile Filter.java: 
122) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) 
        at 
com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(Backen dServersFilter.java: 
97) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) 
        at 
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java: 
388) 
        at 
org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java: 
216) 
        at 
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java: 
182) 
        at 
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java: 
765) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java: 
418) 
        at 
com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEn gineWebAppContext.java: 
70) 
        at 
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java: 
152) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService 
$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351) 
        at 
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java: 
152) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java: 
542) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection 
$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212) 
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) 
        at 
org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java: 
409) 
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool 
$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Powered by Jetty://

Comment: Strip code out of one of your failing JSPs until you have a small example that you can post.

Comment: I guess you are aware that we cannot see your JSP

Comment: You need jdk to run and compile JSP , i think you are using JRE